# Checking Independence for functions in R

Tags: r, self-study, independence

Given

$$f_{(U_1,U_2)}(u_1,u_2)=\begin{cases} 1/2& -u_1<u_2<u_1 \text{ and } u_1 - 2 < u_2 < 2 - u_1 \text{ and } 0 < u_1 <2\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I found that $$f_{(U_1)}(u_1) = \begin{cases} u_1 & 0<u_1<1\\2-u_1 &1<u_1<2 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And $$f_{(U_2)}(u_2) = \begin{cases} 1+u_2 & -1<u_2<0\\1-u_2 &0<u_2<1 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I want to justify whether $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent or not by using R.. I am wondering what is the command is like...Could anyone please give me some directions as for how to check independence for functions in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For independence you want to show that the joint density factorizes, i.e.
$$ f_{12}(u_1,u_2) = f_1(u_1)f_2(u_2), \;\;\; \forall u_1,u_2 \;\;\; (\dagger)$$

where for convenience I've written $f_{12}=f_{(U1,U2)}, f_1=f_{(U1)}, f_2=f_{(U2)}$.

You can't use a tool like R to *prove* that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent. This is because probability densities are continuous and can potentially have an infinite support, whereas computers can only deal with individual numbers and can't handle infinity. In your case, your densities have a finite support, i.e. they're only non-zero near the origin, so this makes things easier. But a computer can't check every single possible value of $u_1$ and $u_2$.

What you can do is to use R to check that plots, etc, are *consistent* with independence. As a general rule, it's a good idea to start by plotting the data (leaving other things aside, it gives you a visual check you haven't made a mistake in translating from math to code). First of all define the range of $u_1$ and $u_2$ and then use `grid` to get R to produce all the points $(u_1,u_2)$ that you're going to want to plot probability densities for.

```
u1=seq(-3,3,0.05);
u2=u1;
grid=expand.grid(u1=u1,u2=u2);
```

Now define your joint density $f_{12}$ and put its results alongside our points

```
f12 = function(u1,u2) { ifelse (-u1 < u2 & u2  < u1 & u1 - 2 < u2 & u2 < 2-u1 & 0 < u1 & u1 < 2, 0.5, 0) }
grid$f12 = with(grid,f12(u1,u2))
```

Note the use of R's `ifelse` function rather than an `if` statement with an accompanying `else`. The former works with vectors, which is what we want.

We can plot this using the `lattice` 3d plotting package (`ggplot2` is another extremely good graphics package).

```
library(lattice)
wireframe(f12~u1*u2,data=grid,shade=TRUE,main="f12", scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

[image]
Now define $f_1$ and $f_2$ and plot them to check they make sense. Note that because computers work with a set of discrete points, I had to change a `<` into a `<=` in both cases.

```
f1=function(u1) { ifelse(0 < u1 & u1 <= 1, u1, ifelse(1 < u1 & u1 < 2, 2-u1, 0)) }
f2=function(u2) { ifelse(-1<u2 & u2<=0, 1+u2, ifelse(0<u2 & u2<1, 1-u2, 0)) }
```

To plot these on top of each other, use the `par` command and R's regular 1d `plot` command.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(f1(u1)~u1, type="l")
plot(f2(u2)~u2, type="l")
```

[image]

Now define a function `f1f2` to represent the product $f_1(u_1)f_2(u_2)$ on the right hand side of $(\dagger)$, put it alongside our points $(u_1,u_2)$ and plot it.

```
f1f2=function(u1,u2) { f1(u1)*f2(u2) }
grid$f1f2=with(grid,f1f2(u1,u2))
wireframe(f1f2~u1*u2,data=grid,shade=TRUE,main="f12", scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

[image]

You don't need to go any further. Clearly the product of the densities is different from the joint distribution, so $U_1$ and $U_2$ are not independent. In other circumstances if you still thought the distributions were independent, you might want to plot their differences, or simply sum their (absolute) differences, as in `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))`.

As a final note, you can actually tell from the *very first plot* of $f_{12}$ that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not independent. If they were independent, then the 3d plot would have borders parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes. As it is, you can see that depending on the values that $U_1$ takes, certain values in the support of $U_2$ are possible or impossible. So clearly there is dependence here. Contrast this with the plot of $f_1f_2$ whose borders are aligned with the axes (a necessary but not sufficient condition for independence). This is illustrated in the plot below, where I plot all the $u_2$s for which $f_{12}\neq0$ against all the $u_1$s for which $f_{12}\neq0$.

```
plot(grid$u2[grid$f12>0] ~ grid$u1[grid$f12>0], ylab=expression(u[2]), xlab=expression(u[1]), main=expression(paste(u[2], plain(" vs "), u[1], plain(" for "), f[12]>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))` will calculate the difference between $f_{U_1}*f_{U_2} - f_{U_1,U_2}(u_1, u_2)$ right...if so and if they are independent,  `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))` will give 0. If they are dependent, we will a number between 0 and 1 right since their total volumn adds up to 1, right?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf yes, if they're independent you'll get zero (however you can't safely say if the abs sum is zero then they're independent for reasons given at the start of my answer). Re if they're dependent, it will be non-zero, yes, but it could be a lot bigger than 1, because we're not taking into account the area "dxdy" as we sum.

Comment: quick note about checking if difference between 2 things is zero: computers store things as bits an are unable to store a general rational number exactly. So you should check if difference between two numbers is small (e.g. 10^(-8)) for example try b <- 0.8 - 0.2; b - 0.6 in R

Comment: are you saying if the difference between two numbers are small, they could still be independent?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I'm saying that you can't _prove_ independence on a computer. Because the densities are continuous, you can only take so many samples, computers can only represent numbers to a limited accuracy (thanks Benjamin), and if the support is $(-\infty,\infty)$ as in the normal distribution say then computers can't represent infinite numbers. To prove it in general you have to do it analytically. Note that emphasis on proof -- we might still be satisfied with something less for practical purposes.

Comment: `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))` does not tell us the whether two variables are independent or not right?

Comment: if `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))` is not equal to zero (allowing for numerical area), then they aren't independent. If it's equal to zero (allowing for numerical area) this is consistent with the variables being independent.

Comment: If `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))` not equal to zero, they are not independent...however you just said you can't prove independence on a computer...are not these two statements contradicting with each other?

Comment: yes, I should clarify: you can disprove independence, but you can't prove it. It's similar to saying it takes one counter-example to disprove a hypothesis, but proving the hypothesis is a much harder thing to do.

Comment: just to have to make sure I know the command: `sum(abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2))`   it basically sums up the areas in f12 but not in f1f2 multiply by it height, f12 associated with the area in f12 not in f1f2....to put it in context, the support for f12 is a square centered at 0 with side 1 and f1f2 is a diamond....if we use f12-f1f2...we have four triangle from each corner...this command sums up the area on top of those four triangles right?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf it's simpler than that. `gridf12` contains all the evaluations of $f_{12}$ on the grid, and `gridf1f2` contains all the evaluations of $f_1f_2$ on the grid. The command `abs(grid$f12-grid$f1f2)` takes the difference between evaluations at the same point and takes the absolute value so differences can't cancel out when you do the `sum` over all points on the grid.

Comment: gridf12 accounts for the volume (grid) right?

Comment: I just think of a quetion: what if two volume are the same, but their support are different...then this command will give 0...what other things we can do to show that they are dependent in this situation?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf re comment(1) `grid$f12` and `grid$f1f2` are the densities, or the heights in the plots. To get to volume, or the total probability you need to multiply by the area given by $0.05$ in the $u_1$ direction $\times0.05$ in the $u_2$ direction. So `sum(grid$f12*0.05*0.05)`$\approx$`sum(grid$f1f2*0.05*0.05)`$\approx1$. But you want to compare densities not total volume. Re (2) if the support of $f_{12}$ and $f_1f_2$ are different then clearly $f_{12}\neq f_1f_2$, and for independence we know $f_{12}=f_1f_2$. This relates to the point I was making in my last para, "As a final note...".

Comment: @tooTone: could you just show me the command for the support $f_{U_1, U_2} (u_1,u_2)$ and $f_{U_1} (u_1)$ * $f_{U_2} (u_2)$ ? I think that will be easier to see they are not independent.

Comment: My question is really could you provide me the command in R for the support for $f_{U_1, U_2} (u_1, u_2)$, which is a diamond in a square with length 1 centered at (1,0)...also I want the command for the support for $f_{U_1} (u_1)$ * $f_{U_2} (u_2)$ which is 0<$U_1$<2 and -1 < $U_2$ < 1...

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this? Basically a 2D- plane

Comment: you know I'm not really sure what you mean. But also, this discussion feels like it's getting beyond the original question and it's difficult to address what you mean in an extended set of comments. Here's what I suggest: (i) decide whether you want to upvote / downvote / accept my answer; (ii) try to take stock of what you've learnt from asking your question (which is a good question), and the answers you have received (iii) formulate a new question based on taking stock, and put that question here is it's stats related or on stackoverflow if it is more related to programming in R. hth

Comment: I just want to show a 2D-plot with $U_1$ in the x-axis and $U_2$ in the y-axis...then plot the support for $f_{U_1, U_2}(U_1,U_2)$ one one graph and another 2D-plot with $U_1$ in the x-axis and $U_2$ in the y-axis...then plot for the support for $f_{U_1}(U_1)f_{U_2}(U_2)$...tell me what part you do not understand...the reason I asked that ... it is easy to from the support to show that they are dependent

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I'm beginning to understand what you mean, but imo it would make sense as another question? I'd happily look at it (I check stats stackoverflow regularly now) as will others. Nevertheless now I (think) I understand what you mean, I think your question is a very interesting one and I've updated my post -- see last para.

Comment: could you draw the line and give the corresponded region colors instead of grid and also do it for f12, and the use par(mfrow=c(2,2)) command to compare them?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do the line automatically. I think it isn't straightforward, but note you can draw a line programmatically using `points`. This is a question you might put on stackoverflow if you want to follow up. To plot $f_{12}$ you just need to substitute `f1f2` for `f12` in the two places it appears in the R code I added, and change `f[12]` to `f[1],f[2]` to get the title right. I just tried it and you get a rectangular grid of `o`s. Not very illuminating really :) But you still might want to include such a plot as a compare and contrast if you were making a formal report.

Comment: the reason I do not put this in stackflow...they cannot decode Latex...do you know any way to get around that?

Comment: yes, just write the latex you need here, or online (e.g. codecogs) and screen grab it and paste it in as an image. If it really is mathematical though, it should be asked here. Your question here was a perfect fit for stats stackexchange. It's just if you have questions about R _programming_ they should be on stackoverflow.

Comment: I am really close here I try to make another graph that $u_2$ vs $u_1$ for f1 > 0 and f2 > 0....my command is the following however it also came with some problem     > plot(grid$u2[grid$f2>0] ~ grid$u1[grid$f1>0], ylab=expression(u[2]), xlab=expression(u[1]), main=expression(paste(u[2], plain(" vs "), u[1], plain(" for "), f[u1]>0, f[u2]>0)))
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
....

Comment: I have the command it's just `plot(grid$u2[grid$f1f2>0] ~ grid$u1[grid$f1f2>0], ylab=expression(u[2]), xlab=expression(u[1]), main=expression(paste(u[2], plain(" vs "), u[1], plain(" for "), f[1],f[2]>0)))`. Like I said not the most spectacularly interesting plot though!

Comment: your command is for joint density...i want one graph only for f1(u1)*f2(u2)

Comment: ok, I think I'm going to have to leave it there at least for now-- I have some deadlines that I'm rapidly falling behind on. If you ask another question you could drop the link here and I'll take a look and help if I can.

Comment: basically I want a square with all the grid centered at (1,0) with side 2

Comment: i got it..the thing I am looking for is the following:plot(grid$u2[grid$f1f2>0] ~ grid$u1[grid$f1f2>0], ylab=expression(u[2]), xlab=expression(u[1]), main=expression(paste(u[2], plain(" vs "), u[1], plain(" for "), f[u1]>0, f[u2]>0)))

Comment: if you do a par and put these two graphs on the same picture...you can easily see they are dependent

Comment: @TooTone: I have a new post which is somewhat related to command in R...If have are interested in it, please feel free to visit the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267737/use-polyroot-or-looking-for-other-ways-to-compute-the-preal-roots

Answer (score 1):

Had you been using data to show that two continuous random variables are independent (i.e., distributions factorize as above), Hoeffding's $D$ test is one to use.  It is implemented in the R `Hmisc` package's `hoeffd` function.  $D$ is a measure of the difference between the product of the two vectors of ranks and the scaled bivariate rank.  Nonparametric statistics texts discuss it in much more detail.

After installing the `Hmisc` package run

```
require(Hmisc)
?hoeffd    # to see documentation, which has this example below
example(hoeffd)   # run examples
# Hoeffding's test can detect even one-to-many dependency
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(-10,10,length=200)
y <- x*sign(runif(200,-1,1))
plot(x,y)   # a large X
hoeffd(x,y)

D
     x    y
x 1.00 0.06
y 0.06 1.00

avg|F(x,y)-G(x)H(y)|
       x      y
x 0.0000 0.0407
y 0.0407 0.0000

max|F(x,y)-G(x)H(y)|
       x      y
x 0.0000 0.0763
y 0.0763 0.0000

n= 200 

P
  x  y 
x     0
y  0
```

The $P$-value for testing $H_0$: $X$ and $Y$ are independent prints as zero.  It is $< 10^{-4}$.

Comment: I haven't heard of it...could you show me how to do it?

Comment: when I run it, it says the following > require(Hmisc)
Loading required package: Hmisc
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘Hmisc’
> ?hoeffd    
No documentation for ‘hoeffd’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??hoeffd’
> example(hoeffd)   
Warning message:
In example(hoeffd) : no help found for ‘hoeffd’
> set.seed(1)
> x <- seq(-10,10,length=200)
> y <- x*sign(runif(200,-1,1))
> plot(x,y)   # a large X
> hoeffd(x,y)
Error: could not find function "hoeffd" How do I fix those issues

Comment: It is best to get more familiar with the workings of R before proceeding, e.g., how to easily download and install packages.  http://RStudio.org makes this especially easy.